# Interesting Python Idiom for removing the only item in a single entry list

Tags: python

Stumbled across this today, thought it might be worthy of discussing.

> Python idiom for taking the single
>   item from a list
>
> It sometimes happens in code that I
>   have a list, let’s call it `stuff`, and
>   I know for certain that this list
>   contains exactly one item. And I want
>   to get this item and put it in a
>   variable, call it thing. What’s the
>   best way to do this? In the past I
>   used to do this:
>
> ```
> thing = stuff[0]
> ```
>
> But I think that’s not the best idiom. I came up
>   with a better one:
>
> ```
> (thing,) = stuff
> ```
>
> Why is this one better?
>
> **Readability**: It lets the reader know
>   that stuff has exactly one element.
>
> **Free assert**: It makes Python assert
>   that `stuff` has exactly one element, so
>   if I was wrong in my original
>   assumption that `stuff` has exactly one
>   element, Python will shout at me
>   before this manifests itself as a
>   hard-to-find bug someplace else in the
>   program.
>
> **Hard to miss**: The previous
>   method had a `[0]` at the end. Now,
>   that’s easy to notice in a line as
>   short as `thing = stuff[0]`. But what if
>   the line were something messy like
>   this:
>
> ```
> thing = some_dict[my_object.get_foobar_handler()][0]
> ```
>
> In this case, the [0] at the end is
>   easy to miss, because when casually
>   glancing the code, it might seem
>   connected to that function call or
>   dict lookup. So the reader might miss
>   the fact that we’re taking an item out
>   of a list here. This would be better
>   in this case:
>
> ```
> (thing,) = some_dict[my_object.get_foobar_handler()]
> ```
>
> **General for any “collection”** (props to
>   Ulrik for noting this): This method
>   works even when stuff is a set or any
>   other kind of collection. `stuff[0]`
>   wouldn’t work on a set because set
>   doesn’t support access by index
>   number. Have fun programming!

(http://blog.garlicsim.org/post/1198230058/python-idiom-for-taking-the-single-item-from-a-list)

In general, I'm torn on the idea.  He makes a compelling argument with the free assert and increased readability (should it become a pattern).  On the other hand, until/if it becomes popular, its a bit harder to read.

What does the community think?

Comment: Without implying merit or otherwise, just thought I'd mention this is also possible without the braces: `thing, = stuff`.

Comment: @Matth: But the trailing comma (without parens) is rather easy to overlook, too.

Answer (score 7):

The blog poster wants a single statement to function as (1) extracting an item from a list, (2) an assert, and (3) as a comment telling the user that the list has only one item.

I'm a huge fan of minimizing the number of lines of code, but I vastly prefer the following:

```
assert len(stuff) == 1, "stuff should have length 1 but has length %d" % len(stuff)
thing = stuff[0]
```

Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: +1: The assert is often necessary.  Surprisingly often.  You may think you know it has one element.  But you have a problem elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer:

```
[thing] = stuff
```

if only because I think `(thing,)` is ugly. But I like the concept in general.

Answer (score 0):

One is likely to miss the comma on its own, and I would rather index stuff over putting brackets, (and that comma), around thing.

I guess I am currently wired to write `thing = stuff[0]`